# Unable to add strings in JSR223 postprocessor

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, post-processor

I am writing below code in JSR223 Post processor

```
def my_number = vars.get("Initial_file_count").toInteger(); //convert to int type
def new_number = 3;

def add = my_number + new_number;

vars.put("MY_NUMBER", add.toString());

log.info(my_number);
```

Comment: What problems do you encounter? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more or less fine apart from the last line which needs to be changed to something like:

```
log.info('My Number: ' + add);
```

because [log.info()](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/apidocs/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.html#info-java.lang.String-) function expects only [Strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/?java/lang/String.html) as arguments so you either need to use string concatenation or [toString()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method of the provided object.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)